# WHERE clause for each Table JOIN slowing down query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-query-builder

So I have three tables that I need to join.

```
$query = Table::where('a.is_deleted', 0)
        ->where('b.is_deleted', 0)
        ->where('c.is_deleted', 0)
        ->leftjoin('b', 'b.mother_id', '=', 'a.mother_id')
        ->leftjoin('c', 'c.material_group_id', '=', 'a.material_group_id')
        ->get();
```

Problem is I have 6,000+ rows on my table and having where clause for each table slows down the query a whole lot.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: To clarify, this is not Eloquent. This is the Query Builder.

Comment: thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing this kind of performance degradation at just 6k rows, the only reason could be that you have no indexes on your table. If you're going to filter a result set on `is_deleted` and join it on some `id` or another, you need to have indexes on those fields. Probably one composite index on each table with the relevant `id` field and the `is_deleted` field. Likewise an index on the `a` table for each of the ids is probably needed.